# ExtJS MVC Stopped Working

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

I am having an issue with ExtJS MVC, I am not sure what happened since until recently I did not have any issues, my main app looks something like this

```
this.sApp = Ext.create('Ext.app.Application', {
        name: 'FileBrowser',
        appFolder: 'fileBrowserApp',
        controllers: ['BrowserController'],
        requires: ['Dashboard.Library'],
        dependencies: {
            css: [],
            js: []
```

Anyway, for some reason the application is looking for the controller in the wrong place, instead of going to `fileBrowserApp/controller/BrowserController' it tries to go to 'FileBrowser/controller/BrowserController.js` for some reason it no longer recognizes the `appFolder` attribute, anyone have any idea why? I am using ExtJs 4.1.

EDIT: Let me try to make a more specific question, why would `Ext.app.Application` try to place the `name` into the application path rather than the `appFolder`? I don't think that's supposed to be happening, Is there another attribute that could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve the issue by creating a workaround by adding the following:

```
      init: function () {
            Ext.Loader.setPath('FileBrowser', '/fullPath/fileBrowserApp');
        },
```

Still not sure, why the original way above stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Ext.application( config );` for the creation of your applications. As normal classes don't have the [appFolder](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Application-cfg-appFolder) property (and no controllers property). Dependencies doesn't exist unless you have your own implementation for it.

**UPDATE:**

if this issue is, you need a reference to the app you can just set it up like this:

```
var context= this;
Ext.create('Ext.app.Application', {
    name: 'FileBrowser',
    appFolder: 'fileBrowserApp',
    controllers: ['BrowserController'],
    requires: ['Dashboard.Library'],
    dependencies: {
        css: [],
        js: []
    }
    init: function() {
        context.sApp = this;
    }
});
```

Comment: Can't, this is the way the architecture is set up and not by me. As mentioned, this seemed to work fine until recently.

Comment: I don't know, I actually thought that perhaps someone changed the ExtJS version but that wasn't to be the case. I was hoping that perhaps someone has some idea as to what could be wrong here. I could go through the entire application and change the relative paths, that would resolve the issue but what if it switches back, would I have to change all the paths to the way they were? I really don't know what happened.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the path by adding the code in App.JS

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({
    enabled: true,
    setPath: {
        'FileBrowser': '/fullPath/fileBrowserApp'
    }
});
```